# how to find out what case style a string is (pascal, snake, kebab, camel)

Tags: c, string, camelcasing, snakecasing, kebab-case

I want to write a program that outputs whether a string is styled in pascal case, camel case, snake case, kebab case, or none of them.
in the first line, we should take integer `n` from input. then, in the next n lines, we should take an integer `k` and then a string with no space in each line. k is the size of the string.
here's an example of how each of these case styles look like:

```
pascal case => HelloWorld
camel case => helloWorld
snake case => hello_world
kebab case => hello-world
```

e.g: input :

```
3
11 masterShifu
12 master_shifu
12 MASTER_SHIFU
```

output:

> camel case
> snake case
> undefined case style

my problem with this program is that I don't know how to find the first letter of each word since there's no space between two different words. this is what i've written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main()
{
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int k;

        scanf("%d ", &k);
        char word[k];

        gets(word[k]);
        int count = 0;

        if (isupper(word[0]) == 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                if (isupper(word[i]) == 1) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count == k)
                printf("Undefined Case Style\n");
            else
                printf("PascalCase\n");
        }
        else {
            int c = 0,
                s = 0,
                count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (word[i] == '-') {
                    c++;
                    printf("kebab-case\n");
                    break;
                }
                else if (word[i] == '_')    // snake case
                {
                    s++;
                    printf("snake_case\n");
                    break;
                }
                else if (isupper(word[i]) == 1) // camel case
                {
                    count++;
                    printf("camelCase\n");
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (c == 0 && s == 0)
                printf("Undefined Case Style\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't look for spaces. Look for either `_`, `-`, or a letter that's the opposite case of the letter before it.

Comment: [Don't use gets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gets).  It is unsafe and deprecated.  Not to mention, you are sending a single character to it `gets(word[k]);` which is meaningless.  How did that even compile?  Turn on your warnings in whatever compiler you're using, and switch to `fgets`.  The beginning of the word will just be the first non-white-space character in the string returned by `fgets`.

Comment: I suggest you define more precisely what each means.  For instance what is `a-b_c`, `AbC`.  A great way to document hard-coding test cases in `main()`.

Comment: Also remember to skip/trim leading an trailing whitespace  c.f. `isspace()`.

Comment: Make yourself some helper functions, `containsUpper( const char *str )`, `containsLower( const char *str )`, `containsLetter( const char *str, char letter )`.  A good approach might be to rule-out all the *malformed* combinations first, and per @AllanWind's comment.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you iterate through the input string `s` then given current character `*s` and what case `found` you have found determine if the `*s` is a valid and what the new `found` is or you can terminate processing.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum str_case {
    CAMEL,
    KEBAB,
    PASCAL,
    SNAKE,
    UNDEFINED,
};

enum str_case str2str_case(const char *s) {
    enum str_case found = isupper(*s++) ? PASCAL : UNDEFINED;
    for(; *s; s++) {
        if(*s == '-') {
            if(found == KEBAB)
                continue;
            if(found == UNDEFINED) {
                found = KEBAB;
                continue;
            }
            return UNDEFINED;
        }
        if(*s == '_') {
            if(found == SNAKE)
                continue;
            if(found == UNDEFINED) {
                found = SNAKE;
                continue;
            }
            return UNDEFINED;
        }
        if(isupper(*s)) {
            if(found == CAMEL || found == PASCAL)
                continue;
            if(found == UNDEFINED) {
                found = CAMEL;
                continue;
            }
            return UNDEFINED;
        }
        if(!islower(*s))
            return UNDEFINED;
    }
    return found;
}

int main(void) {
    struct test {
        char *input;
        enum str_case expected;
    } tests[] = {
        {"helloWorld", CAMEL},
        {"hello-world", KEBAB},
        {"HelloWorld", PASCAL},
        {"hello_world", SNAKE},
        {"", UNDEFINED},
        {"!", UNDEFINED},
        {"A-b", UNDEFINED},
        {"a_b-c", UNDEFINED},
    };
    for(struct test *t = tests; t < tests + sizeof tests / sizeof *tests; t++) {
        enum str_case got = str2str_case(t->input);
        if(t->expected != got) {
            printf("fail: %s: expected %d but got %d\n", t->input, t->expected, got);
            continue;
        }
        printf("ok\n");
    }
}
```

and here is the output:

```
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
```

I would then refactor the code with the macro:

```
#define CHECK(char_predicate, state_predicate, new_state) \
    if((char_predicate)) {\
        if((state_predicate))\
            continue;\
        if(found == UNDEFINED) {\
            found = (new_state);\
            continue;\
        }\
        return UNDEFINED;\
    }
```

and the function becomes simply:

```
enum str_case str2str_case(const char *s) {
    enum str_case found = isupper(*s++) ? PASCAL : UNDEFINED;
    for(; *s; s++) {
        CHECK(*s == '-', found == KEBAB, KEBAB);
        CHECK(*s == '_', found == SNAKE, SNAKE);
        CHECK(isupper(*s), found == CAMEL || found == PASCAL, CAMEL);
        if(!islower(*s))
            return UNDEFINED;
    }
    return found;
}
```

Other than `fgets()` instead of `gets()` you didn't seem to have issues with parsing the input format, and generating the expected output format so leaving that as an exercise to reader.